# HTML5 doc from scratch with HAML

Tags: haml

I'm learning HAML. If I create a basic HAML file like so:

```
%h2 Hello World
This is a test
```

and run HAML on the command line:

```
haml somehaml.haml someout.html
```

the resulting html file doesn't have `<head>` or `<body>` tags:

```
<h2>Hello World</h2>
This is a test
```

What am I missing? According to the [documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html), html5 should be the default output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to add the tags. html 5 or not is mostly a case of what is in the document type header and that is html 5 by default. Try this:

```
%html
  %head
  %body
    %h2 Hello World
    This is a test
```